# Como compartilhar variáveis no Crystal Reports

Tags: variáveis, crystal-reports

Tenho uma variável no meu report e gostaria de utilizar ela em um sub-report.

Como faço isto?

Comment: Tenta dar mais detalhes do seu problema...

Answer (score 3):

Você pode criar uma variável dentro de uma fórmula da seguinte forma (utilizando Basic Sintax):

```
shared variavel as string

variavel = "teste"

formula = variavel
```

Não esquecer que esta fórmula deve ficar em um nível hierárquico superior ao sub-report.

Aí, dentro do seu sub-relatório, crie uma outra fórmula para consumí-la (também com Basic Sintax):

```
shared variavel as string

variavel = variavel + " de variavel compartilhada"

formula = variavel
```

Para que a primeira fórmula não apareça basta marcar como *Suppress*.

O resultado, dentro do seu sub-relatório deve ser "teste de variavel compartilhada".